# vuejs2 not evaluating variable inside double quotes

Tags: vuejs2

I have a loop like this:

```
 <ul class="menu-list" v-for="artist in artists">
   <li> <a href="/artist/{{artist.artist}}">{{ artist.artist }}</a> </li>
 </ul>
```

everything in my code works well, but the `/artist/{{artist.artist}}` part isn't evaluated. I just get something like `/artist/%7B%7Bartist.artist%7D%7D`

In vue 1.x it used to work well, but not in vue2

Answer (score 4):

Because it doesn't work like that in v2 anymore: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed

---

If you don't want to change code too much then this should do:

```
<a :href="'/artist/' + artist.artist">
```

However, if you are using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) then you should use
`<router-link>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: You can also make it a little more readable using template literals. `<a :href="\`/artist/${artist.artist}\`">`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one as i have solved my problem using this

```
<ul class="menu-list" v-for="artist in artists">
   <li> <a :href='"/artist/" + artist.artist'>@{{ artist.artist }}</a> </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: How does this differ from [Traxo's 2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476295)?

Comment: opps! I didn't see that, actually, I am new  here, her answer is also correct

Answer (score 0):

i hope you have solved your problem but if not this is the way you can do it. you need to call a method in your vue which will return the value for your link.

```
<ul class="menu-list" v-for="artist in artists">
   <li> <a :href="artistlink(artist.artist)">{{ artist.artist }}/a> </li>
 </ul>
```

now in your method section make a method like this

```
methods: {
    artistlink(value){
            if(value==null ||value=='') return ;
            return '/artist/'+value;
        },  

}
```

The above function also works for numeric loops.